# Client Application not Redirect to Identity Server 4 after hosted in iss

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

Client Application(core 3.1) not redirect to Identity Server 4(core 3.1) application after hosted in iis.  can any one tell me reasons

Exceptions:

---> System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: 'https://***********/IdentityServer/.well-known/openid-configuration'.

---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.

---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

Thank You

Comment: Can you please post the error log you are getting?

Comment: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

Comment: Please check validity of the certificate. If it is valid and you are still getting this error try this link : [github thread](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/2864)

Comment: thank you for your response.It helped me in solving the issue

Comment: Glad I could be of help, you can post the solution you got as an answer to this question. It would be helpful for others! Cheers !!!

Comment: If you found my answer helpful please mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says:

```
System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
```

The certificate you are using is invalid, hence re-check the validity and use the valid one.